# Constrain bandwidth on a network interface

Tags: networking, tc

I want to limit bandwidth on the `wlp2s0` network interface of my laptop.

As far as I understood `tc`, it should be the tool to go. So I tried the following:

```
tc qdisc add dev wlp2s0 root handle 1: htb default 1
tc class add dev wlp2s0 parent 1: classid 1:1 htb rate 10mbps ceil 10mbps
```

As per `tc`'s manpage, this last command should ensure minimum 10mbps and maximum 10mbps egress traffic for the `1:1` class.

What I expected to see is that my upload bandwidth will be limited to those 10mbps. However, that did not happen. Measured using `iperf3`, my upload bandwidth is the same as it was before.

Comment: What's the iperf3 command you used to measure?

Comment: @Peregrino69 I have a remote server where I run `iperf3 -s -1`, on the side of my laptop I run `iperf3 -c IP_OF_REMOTE`. That should measure the egress bandwidth of my laptop. Measured bandwidth is far more than 10mbps, same as if I didn't have my `qdisc` in place.